# What is the difference between the selectors ".class.class" and ".class .class"?

Tags: css, css-selectors

What is the different between `.class.class` and `.class .class`?

Comment: The first selects the element which has both classes. The latter select an element which has the class `class` which has a parent which has the class `class`

Comment: In order to make everything more understandable I think it would be better to distinguish the classes in `class1` and `class2`

Answer (score 134, accepted):

`.class .class` matches any elements of class `.class` that are **descendants** of another element with the class `.class`.

`.class.class` matches any element with both classes.

Comment: For the latter, does the order matter?

Comment: @ClarusDignus , in case of .class.class, order doesn't matter. Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5tw8rm58/).

Comment: @NoopurDabhi Understood. Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 96):

1. `.name1.name2`

   means a `div` or an `element` having both classes together, for example:

   ```
   <div class="name1 name2">...</div>
   ```

---

2. `.name1 .name2`

   means a `div` or an `element` which has a class `name1` and any of its child nodes having class `name2`

   ```
   <div class="name1">
       <div class="name2">
           ...
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

Answer (score 23):

```
.class1.class2
```

Element that has both `class1` and `class2` set within it's `class` attribute (like that: `class="class1 class2"`)

```
.class1 .class2
```

Element with `class2` that is a descendant of an element with `class1` class

Comment: This is the most understandable answer, IMO.

Comment: Yet I can't even read it without getting confused lol and im a webdev

Comment: @nbro no, this is more easy to understand https://stackoverflow.com/a/17391614/8618055

Answer (score 4):

`.class.class` can also be used to avoid the use of `!important` in case that a higher specificity selector prevents your rule from being applied.

In this case there are not two classes in the HTML element. You only repeat the class which specificity you want to increase in the style (selector), like

```
(HTML) <div class="something">...</div>

(CSS) .something.something {}
```

Answer (score 1):

**.class1.class2:** Selects all elements with class2 that is a descendant of an element with class1

**.class1 .class2:** Selects all elements with both class1 and class2 set within its class attribute

```
Lets see with code example:
```

```css
.class1.class2{
  color: red;
}

.class1 .class2{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1 class2">
  Hi I am ".class1.class2" selector
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <p class="class2">
    Hi I am ".class1 .class2" selector
  </p>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle link for better ref: https://jsfiddle.net/srikrushna_pal/16dw3n0u/3/