# .class .class same classname selector in css

Tags: html, css

Can anyone explain me what does the below css do?

```
.validate-error .validate-error {
  color: #cc2424;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.make-switch + .validate-error {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

In the first css i see the `same class name` used twice?. Is this css valid?. I came across this thread 
[What is the difference between the selectors ".class.class" and ".class .class"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391364/what-is-a-difference-between-the-selectors-class-class-vs-class-class)
but unsure whether its applicable if we use the **same class name twice**?.

Comment: even `.validate-error.validate-error` (without space in between) is valid and sometimes is used as a hack to increase specificity, but that's the other case...

Comment: @davidcondrey - no it wouldn't: it just means the class needs to exist once: `.name.name` would match `class="name"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one styles child elements/descendant with the same class name:

```
<div class="validate-error">
    This color may be different from #cc2424
    <div class="validate-error">Has color #cc2424</div>
</div>
```

This means: The styles are applied/overwritten for child elements with the same class name.

---

The second one styles siblings:

```
<div class="make-switch"></div>
<div class="validate-error">Has left margin</div>
<div class="validate-error">Has no left margin</div>
```

That means: Only if `.make-switch` is followed by `.validate-error` the styles are applied to `.validate-error`.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/snsrzc4w/)

Answer (score 2):

```
.validate-error .validate-error {
  ...
}
```

This css targets a class `.validate-error` that is a descendant of `.validate-error`.

For example

```
<div class="validate-error">
    <div class="validate-error">
    </div>
</div>
```

Next css targets the class `.validate-error` when it is right next to `.make-switch`

```
.make-switch + .validate-error {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when selector parts are stuck together without whitespace it means it should all match the same element.

example: (should only match an element having both `validate-error` and `other-class` as classes)

```
.validate-error.other-class
```

when there is whitespace between them you are selecting an element that has `other-class` as a class and has a `parent element` with the `validate-error` class

the `+` in your second selector actually means you don't want a child of `make-switch` but you want the `sibling` element, but only if it has class `validate-error`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is valid. There are no rules in CSS preventing a class name appearing multiple times in a complex selector. There are no rules in HTML preventing two elements, one of which is a descendant of the other, from sharing membership of a class.

Answer (score 0):

Id only should be unique, but classname we can use multiple times.